# JWT Token vs Default token in Asp.net Web Api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, jwt

I want to build a web application with angularJs in the front and Asp.net web api in the back end , i did a lot of searching onhow to secure my backend server , I found that a lot of articles talk about the benifits of JWT token (JSON Web Token) but in the default Asp.net web application project there is already an access Token implemented :

```
     // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

If anyone can help me please , to understand the difference between JWT token and the Default token in asp.net web Api authentification system ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: JWTs are more secure and reliable. It is strongly suggested to use them. Also, the most convenient way to secure Asp.NET Web Api  is using thinktecture IdentityServer, rather than the default feature you are using. This default token generator won't exist as of the next version of Asp.Net, and the thinktecture IdentityServer will replace it.

Comment: I would hardly consider Thinktectures IdentityServer convenient.  While is is a powerful system, it is not simple to setup and the documentation is difficult to follow.  Also I do not believe that Thinktecture IdentityServer is replacing the auth system in the next version of .NET.  There is a new ASP.NET Identity system in vNext (version 5)